# convert many lists in wide format to long format

Tags: r, reshape

I want to convert thousands of lists from wide to long format, given thousands of lists look like this:

```
   y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017 y2018 y2019 coverage_fraction
4     12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.0005232538
9     12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.1390771568
10    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.7728050947
. 
.
46    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12      0.0005232538
```

Is there a way to place `pivot_longer(-c(11)` into a function, like `mapply()`, that changes the columns from each list into long format, whilst retaining the individual list elements?

Essentially, I want to use this code:

```
lc_extract_pred <- landcover %>% 
  exact_extract(r_cells, progress = FALSE) %>% *Convert from wide to long here* %>%
  map(~ count(., landcover=value)) %>% 
  tibble(id = r_cells$id, data = .) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

If I could `pivot_longer()`, then the values from the years will usually be given a column name assigned `value`, hence assigning `landcover=value`in map, and turning this into `tibble()` format.

```
dat_list %>% map_lgl(function(x) pivot_longer(-c(11)) )
```

> Error in UseMethod("pivot_longer") :
> no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class   "c('double', 'numeric')"

Here's a reproducible code containg one row and a few lists:

```
list(c(y2010 = 1, y2011 = 1, y2012 = 1, y2013 = 1, y2014 = 1, 
y2015 = 1, y2016 = 1, y2017 = 1, y2018 = 1, y2019 = 1, coverage_fraction = -1.33003238502638
), c(y2010 = 1, y2011 = 1, y2012 = 1, y2013 = 1, y2014 = 1, y2015 = 1, 
y2016 = 1, y2017 = 1, y2018 = 1, y2019 = 1, coverage_fraction = 0.682342381930735
), c(y2010 = 1, y2011 = 1, y2012 = 1, y2013 = 1, y2014 = 1, y2015 = 1, 
y2016 = 1, y2017 = 1, y2018 = 1, y2019 = 1, coverage_fraction = -2.09817126581704
), c(y2010 = 1, y2011 = 1, y2012 = 1, y2013 = 1, y2014 = 1, y2015 = 1, 
y2016 = 1, y2017 = 1, y2018 = 1, y2019 = 1, coverage_fraction = -0.0942304747486628
), c(y2010 = 1, y2011 = 1, y2012 = 1, y2013 = 1, y2014 = 1, y2015 = 1, 
y2016 = 1, y2017 = 1, y2018 = 1, y2019 = 1, coverage_fraction = -0.944268346233405
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transpose every element in `dat_list` and `rbind` them together.

```
result <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(dat_list, t))

#  y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017 y2018 y2019 coverage_fraction
#1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       -1.33003239
#2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1        0.68234238
#3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       -2.09817127
#4     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       -0.09423047
#5     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1       -0.94426835
```

Or with `purrr`'s `map_df` :

```
purrr::map_df(dat_list, ~as.data.frame(t(.x)))
```